# C Program to reduce rational number to its lowest form using Structures

Tags: c, data-structures

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct
    {
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
    }RATIONAL;
    void reduce(RATIONAL *r1,RATIONAL *r2)
    {
        int a,b,rem;
        if(r1->numerator > r1->denominator)
        {
            b=r1->denominator;
            a=r1->numerator;
        }
        else{
            a=r1->denominator;
            b=r1->numerator;
        }
        while(b!=0)
        {
            rem=a%b;
            a=b;
            b=rem;
        }
        r2->numerator/=a;
        r2->denominator/=a;
    }
    int main()
    {
        RATIONAL r1={24,12};
        RATIONAL red;
        reduce(&r1,&red);
        printf("%i/%i",red.numerator,red.denominator);
    }
```

I am getting a vague answer not at all matching the desired output(for ref. output =350066/4). I don't understand why that's happening. Can please tell me what is wrong in this code.
Thank You!

Comment: `red.numerator` is used uninitialized in this code. Undefined behavior.

Comment: You don’t need the conditional code before the GCD calculation. The calculation loop works fine anyway.

Comment: Your result setting lines should be of the form `r2->x = r1->x / a;`, I believe.

Comment: @melpomene i passed the struct variable `red` by reference

Comment: If your `reduce()` function (in terms of functionality) receives a `RATIONAL` and returns a `RATIONAL`, shouldn't it be better (simpler and clearer) to declare it as `RATIONAL reduce(RATIONAL r1)`?

Comment: @SumantKumar Irrelevant. You're using the value of `r2->numerator` before it has been set.

Comment: @melpomene Oh yeah I see I get my mistake,  thank you very much!